# Kelvin and kinetic theory of gases

Tags: temperature, ideal-gas, degrees-of-freedom

I know that the degree of freedom increase by 2 when the temperature is high and decrease by 2 when the temperature is low. A dumb question here, what temperature is considered as 'high temperature' and what temperature is considered low temperature' to let the degree changes?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the gas in question. The question is probably about the rotational degrees of freedom. At room temperature, the rotation of diatomic molecules behaves like in classical physics. But more accurately, the angular momentum of the atoms is quantized and the rotational kinetic energy is not a continuum by quantized.

So when $kT$ is small, this discretization becomes noticeable. It depends on the angular momentum of the molecule at what temperature this is. And it is gradual.

(But there is also very high temperature, when vibration starts to behave as a classical harmonic oscillator. This gives two additional degrees of freedom, one from kinetic energy, one from potential energy.)